# Como comparar 2 HashMaps diferentes em Java

Tags: java, comparação, hashmap

Eu tenho 2 Strings que converto para HashMaps, a primeira é uma entrada que o usuário dá ao aplicativo. A segunda é um Array que contém um monte de palavras.

Eu preciso comparar ambos os HashMaps para verificar se a entrada pode ser reorganizada para corresponder a uma das palavras do Array. Não há necessidade de usar cada char da entrada do usuário para o sistema, pode haver alguma sobra de char do primeiro HashMap, mas eu preciso ter certeza de que eles podem combinar uma das palavras do Array (o segundo HashMap).

Esse é o código para criar o primeiro HashMap:

```
String normalizedInputWord = normalizeString(inputWord);

Map<Character, Integer> countDuplicateMapInput = new HashMap<>();

char[] charInputArray = normalizedInputWord.toCharArray();

for (char c: charInputArray) {
    if (countDuplicateMapInput.containsKey(c)) {
        countDuplicateMapInput.put(c, countDuplicateMapInput.get(c) + 1);
    } else {
        countDuplicateMapInput.put(c, 1);
    }
}
```

Esse é o segundo HashMap:

```
Map<Character, Integer> countDuplicateMapArray = new HashMap<>();

for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    // Chama uma função para normalizar cada String do Array wordArray
    String normalizedWordArray = normalizeString(wordArray[i]);

    char[] charWordArray = normalizedWordArray.toCharArray();

    for (char c : charWordArray) {
        if (countDuplicateMapArray.containsKey(c)) {
            countDuplicateMapArray.put(c, countDuplicateMapArray.get(c) + 1);
        } else {
            countDuplicateMapArray.put(c, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Como posso comparar essas 2 estruturas e obter uma resposta "true" ao exemplo abaixo?

Exemplo:
O input é "unstoppable" e o HashMap countDuplicateMapInput vai receber:

```
{
key: "p", value: 2;
key: "a", value: 1;
key: "b", value: 1;
key: "s", value: 1;
key: "t", value: 1;
key: "u", value: 1;
key: "e", value: 1;
key: "l", value: 1;
key: "n", value: 1;
key: "o", value: 1;
}
```

e tem a palavra "stop" no meu Array que vai popular o HashMap countDuplicateMapArray da seguinte forma:

```
{
key: "p", value: 1;
key: "t", value: 1;
key: "s", value: 1;
key: "o", value: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei uma resposta que resolveu o meu problema e vou deixar ela registrada aqui caso alguém esteja com o mesmo problema.

```
countDuplicateMapArray.entrySet().stream()
     .allMatch(e -> countDuplicateMapInput.getOrDefault(e.getKey(), 0) >= e.getValue());
```